Flutter plugin ios side not taking cpp paths like #include "opencv2/core/core_c.h"
#core_c.h is working
but
#include "opencv2/core/core_c.h" is not working in flutter plugin ios side, tried all podspec configs but did not work .
File path :
face_verification_plugin->ios->dependencies->include(opencv & opencv2 folders)
Note this is part of viage sdk ios library. I am trying to integrate visage in flutter.
Cocapod version : 1.15.2
Visage SDK Version : 9.1
This is my current podspec file :
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'face_verification_plugin'
  s.version          = '0.0.8'
  s.summary          = 'A new Flutter project.'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
A new Flutter project.
                       DESC
  s.homepage         = 'http://example.com'
  s.license          = { :file => '../LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Your Company' => 'email@example.com' }
  s.source           = { :path => '.' }
  s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*', 'include/**/*' , 'LivenessSupportClasses/**/*', 'GrabberClasses/**/*','dependencies/include/**/*', 'dependencies/include/opencv/**/*'
  s.public_header_files = 'Classes/**/*.h' , 'LivenessSupportClasses/**/*.h', 'GrabberClasses/**/*.h'
  s.dependency 'Flutter'
  s.platform = :ios, '12.0'
  s.libraries = 'z', 'c++', 'a', 'stdc++'
  s.frameworks = 'AVFoundation', 'CoreGraphics', 'CoreMedia', 'CoreVideo', 'ImageIO', 'QuartzCore', 'OpenGLES', 'MobileCoreServices', 'UIKit'
  s.preserve_paths = 'dependencies/include/opencv/**/*'

  s.pod_target_xcconfig = {


    'ENABLE_BITCODE' => 'NO',
    'GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS' => 'VISAGE_STATIC=1 IOS=1',
    'OTHER_CFLAGS' => '-Wno-comment -fms-extensions',
    'DEFINES_MODULE' => 'YES',
    'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'i386',
    'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"${PODS_ROOT}/dependencies/include" $(inherited)',
  }
end

